# GridSearchCV gives different results than LassoCV for optimal alpha

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, lasso-regression, gridsearchcv

I am aware of the standard process of finding the optimal value of alpha/lambda using Cross Validation technique through `GridSearchCV` class in `sklearn.model_selection` library.Here's my code to find that .

```
    alphas=np.arange(0.0001,0.01,0.0005)
    cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=3, random_state=100)

    hyper_param = {'alpha':alphas}

    model = Lasso()

    model_cv = GridSearchCV(estimator = model,
                        param_grid=hyper_param,
                        scoring='r2',
                        cv=cv,
                        verbose=1,
                        return_train_score=True
                       )

   model_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
   #checking the bestscore
   model_cv.best_params_
```

This gives me `alpha=0.01`

Now, looking on `LassoCV` , as per my understanding , this library creates model by selecting best optimal `alpha` by the passed `alphas` list, and please note , I have used the same cross validation scheme for both of them. But when trying `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV` with RepeatedKFold cross validation scheme.

```
alphas=np.arange(0.0001,0.01,0.0005)
cv=RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10,n_repeats=3,random_state=100)
ls_cv_m=LassoCV(alphas,cv=cv,n_jobs=1,verbose=True,random_state=100)
ls_cv_m.fit(X_train_reduced,y_train)
print('Alpha Value %d'%ls_cv_m.alpha_)
print('The coefficients are {}',ls_cv_m.coef_)
```

I get `alpha=0` for the same data and this alpha value in not present in the list of decimal values passed in `alphas` argument for this.
This has confused me about the actual implementation of `LassoCV`.
and my doubts are ..

- Why do I get optimal alpha as `0` in `LassoCV` when the list passed to the argument does not has `zero` in it.
- What is the difference between `LassoCV` and `Lasso` then, if I have to anyways find most suitable alpha from `GridSearchCV` only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should pass your *alphas* as keywords parameters rather then positional parameters since the first positional parameter for LassoCV is *eps*.

```
ls_cv_m=LassoCV(alphas=alphas,cv=cv,n_jobs=1,verbose=True,random_state=100)
```

Then, the model is returning as optimal parameter one of the alphas that you previously defined, however you are simply printing it as an integer number casting the float to int. Replace %d with %f to print it in the float format:

```
print('Alpha Value %f'%ls_cv_m.alpha_)
```

Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) for more details about Python printing formats and styles.

As for your second question, Lasso is the linear model while LassoCV is an iterative process that allows you to find the optimal parameters for a Lasso model using Cross-validation.

Comment: thanks @Davide.. I was really getting frustrated with its output, although I can now see my mistakes. Your clean answer really helped me in this Christmas :)